# Div Tag Will NOT Center?

Tags: css, center

In doing my coding, I am trying to have my div "hold" be fixed when the screen scrolls and be centered. I have divs inside of the which are the logo and the navigation which will all go down the page when it scrolls.

For some reason, after trying everything, I can not get the div "hold" to center on the page.

```
#hold {
width: 900px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
position:fixed;
}
```

Here is a live view of the site incase you wanted to see the rest of the code, 
http://fuse.orgfree.com/Portfolio%202012/
The div with the logo should be much farther to the center but it just wont go.

Any and all assistance is appreciated! Thanks alot!

Comment: Here let me Google that for you, https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=CSS+Centered+Div&safe=active

Answer (score 2):

The `position: fixed` is what is causing your hold div to not center properly. Remove that line and the div moves to the center of the page.

Comment: But then how will I keep the div fixed then?

Comment: If you want to keep the position fixed, you need to move it to the center of the screen using the "left" attribute. If you want it to stay centered (horizontally) as the window resizes, you have to use percentages instead of fixed pixel amounts.

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS to your hold div:

```
#hold {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -450px;
}
```

The margin-left property should be half the width of your div.

Answer (score 2):

A example of a `div`,

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

which is fully centered with and fixed with the following style:

```
.center{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    background-color: blue;
}​
```

You can find a demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n6gUj/).

To center it horizontally only:

```
.center{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    background-color: blue;
}​
```

Make the div's content also [centered](http://jsfiddle.net/n6gUj/1/) or make it [fluid](http://jsfiddle.net/n6gUj/2/).